# Javascript not working in React component rendered into shadow dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events, shadow-dom

I'm trying to render a React app/component into shadow dom, because the site is not a spa and I'm following this: https://medium.com/rate-engineering/winning-the-war-of-css-conflicts-through-the-shadow-dom-de6c797b5cba.

Css is getting rendered into the shadow dom but all Javascript is in the bundle and doesn't seem to bind the correct events on controllers inside the shadow dom.In the below example then dropdown is rendered but clicking it doesn't do anything.

**mycomponent.js**

```
import './createShadowRoot';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Dropdown from 'react-dropdown';
import 'react-dropdown/style.css'

const options = [
    { value: '1', label: '1 person' },
    { value: '2', label: '2 persons' },
    { value: '3', label: '3 persons' },
];

class MyComponent extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Dropdown options={options} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const shadowRoot = document.getElementById('root').shadowRoot;
const reactRoot = document.createElement('div');
reactRoot.setAttribute('id', 'react-root');
shadowRoot.appendChild(reactRoot);
ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, reactRoot);
```

**createShadowRoot.js**

```
const shadowHost = document.getElementById('root');
shadowHost.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a similar issue, upgrading react to version 17 or higher fixed it.